# filling redux-form initialValues using mapStateToProps with ASYNC Redux State

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm trying to use `initialValues` to load my form like so:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  item: state.routes.members.item,
  initialValues: {
    id: state.routes.members.item.id,
    member: state.routes.members.item.name,
    description: state.routes.members.item.description
  }
})

const FormControls = reduxForm({
  form: 'editMember',
  getFormState: (state) => state.routes.members.form,
  onSubmit: (values, dispatch) => dispatch(ACTION_CREATORS.EDIT_MEMBER(editAdapter(values))),
  enableReinitialize: true
  }, mapStateToProps)(themable(MembersEdit))

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(FormControls)
```

But I get errors before the state has been read, saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null` . Then the form can not load. Is there some way around this?

Thanks

Comment: that's because item.id is not defined initially.. you should grab `state.routes.members.item` from the store and then check whether this item actually exists in your component before trying to access properties of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure if `state.routes.members.item` is `defined` and not `null`.
Here, you are trying to access the value of 
 `state.routes.members.item` (possibly `null object`). 
You may try something like this.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   let initValues;

   if( state.routes.members && state.routes.members.item) {
       initValues = {
         id: state.routes.members.item.id,
         member: state.routes.members.item.name,
         description: state.routes.members.item.description
      };
   }
   return {
      item: state.routes.members.item,
      initialValues: initValues
   };
}
```

Comment: great thanks, I just assumed that mapStateToProps would re-run on state change.

Comment: mapStateToProps will definitely re-run but there was an error thus it halts and doesn't re-run.
Initially, `state.routes.members.item` was null and then it halts because of the error ( `state.routes.members.item.id` where `state.routes.members.item` was null ).